# can not create xml Parser progress error 11773

Tags: web-services, openedge, progress-4gl

i have the next question, when i try to recive a web service message with this code

```html
RUN importRequest IN hRequest(INPUT DATASET request, OUTPUT returnCode, OUTPUT returnMessage, OUTPUT DATASET resultDset ).
```

but i recive the next message

> Error receiving Web Service Response: Input Stream is Empty. Cannot
>   create XMLParser.(11773)

and when i enter in the web service the register was created . 
thanks for our time and help.

im tryed all types of solutions and I can't resolved it please i need help.

Answer (score 0):

The Progress Knowledge base has a number of articles on that error:

- https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/Error-11773-input-stream-is-empty-Cannot-create-XMLParser-when-sending-SOAP-request
- https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/Error-11773-is-being-returned-by-the-ABL-Web-Service-client-if-a-compressed-HTTP-response-message-is-received-from-a-third-party-Web-Service

Looks like the Web service response is simply not supported by Progress Software. If you're on 11.6 use the new HTTP client in the ABL to communicate with the Web service.

Here's an sample that shows how to use the HTTP client to communicate with a SOAP web service:

https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/How-to-Http-Client-to-save-attachment-from-SOAP-response

Comment: this options dont work for me because i have this error when i recive the SOAP answare in the OUTPUT DATASET resultDset

Comment: If you use the HTTP client, you'll be receiving an X-DOCUMENT are the response Entity. You can READ-XML into a ProDataset from an X-DOCUMENT or X-NODEREF as well.